# Conservation of charge and quantisation of charge

Tags: charge, conservation-laws, discrete

How does the idea of conservation of charge relate to the quantisation of charge.

Comment: Why do you think they are related?

Comment: For the most famous speculation about quantization of charge, a search term is [Dirac quantization condition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.13403).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charge properties were [studied for centuries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge#History) ,

> [Electric charge is a conserved property;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) the net charge of an isolated system, the amount of positive charge minus the amount of negative charge, cannot change.

and when finally the theory of [classical electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) was formed, conservation of charge was inherent in forming of the theory, so as to fit the data.

Quantization of charge is barely a century old, when experiments started studying the microcosm or particles beginning with the [electron.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#History) .

Once it was experimentally established that individual particles with specific charges carried charge, the connection is simple arithmetic calculations.